# Why can't we execute multiple statements of BigQuery in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, google-bigquery, gsutil

I have observed when we run a simple gsutil or bq statements in windows command prompt they will run successfully

ex 1 : `gsutil cp Desktop\MyTraffic.csv gs://BI/`

ex 2 : `bq load --autodetect --replace --source_format=CSV myDataSet.myTable gs://BI/MyTraffic.csv`

but if we run them both in using a batch file like 'runbq.bat' , only first statement will run and the command prompt will terminate immediately without any error

Even adding a pause statement between them won't hold the command prompt window

**runbq.bat :**

```
gsutil cp Desktop\MyTraffic.csv gs://BI/ 
pause
bq load --autodetect --replace --source_format=CSV myDataSet.myTable gs://BI/MyTraffic.csv
```

Comment: Have you checked that the escaping is correctly done? Usually that's the first to double check. Maybe does some escape and yield an invalid command, redirect the output too see logs.

Comment: Use `call` command before each of your BQ statements: `call gsutil cp Desktop\MyTraffic.csv gs://BI/`

Comment: @Aacini Yeah Thanks ,call statement worked.. But May I know reason behind statement call as alternative

Comment: Because `gsutil` and `bq` commands are Batch file themselves: `gsutil.bat` and `bq.bat`. When a Batch file invokes another one without `call` command, the execution is just _transferred_ to the other file, so when the second Batch file ends, the whole proces ends. In order to invoke a second Batch file and return to the first one when the second one ends, it is necessary to add the `call` command.

Comment: @Aacini yeah Thanks a lot for explaining the details

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini), when running a batch script within a **"master"** batch script, it is required to use the `call` command in order to pause the execution of the current batch file and wait until the **called** batch file completes; in this way the process can return and continue in the original flow. However, when the `call` command is not added, the original batch file stops and the **called** batch file starts executing without returning to the original flow.

Another possibility is to use the `start` command instead in case you don't want to lock the **"master"** script.